# Access an Array in Classes C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So I'm busy with my assignment, and I wrote a piece of code that works perfectly, but, its not ready yet.  What I can figure out is how to use an array in a class. or how to get and set the items in the array, and where do I put the loop to prompt the user for the marks.

So I want to prompt the user to enter the assignment number and marks of 3 assignments, that is stored in the array and then output the assignment and the mark.  I know it sounds stupid but it will help me understand arrays in classes.

My class is in an external file here it is

```
    #ifndef ASSIGNMENTS_H_INCLUDED
#define ASSIGNMENTS_H_INCLUDED
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    class assignments
    {
        public:
            assignments(); // default constructor

            void setAssNum(int k); // mutator
            int getAssNum(); // accessor
            void setAssMark(double m); // mutator
            double getAssMark(); // accessor
        private:
            int AssNum;
            double AssMark;
    };



    assignments::assignments()
    {
        AssNum = 0;
        AssMark = 0.0;
    }

    void assignments::setAssNum(int k)
    {
        AssNum = k;
    }
    void assignments::setAssMark(double m)
    {
        AssMark = m;
    }
    int assignments::getAssNum()
    {
        return AssNum;
    }
        double assignments::getAssMark()
    {
        return AssMark;
    }

#endif // ASSIGNMENTS_H_INCLUDED
```

And here is the main

```
int main()
{
    int AssNum;
    double AssMark;
assignments c;

cout <<"Enter Assignment Number: ";
cin >> AssNum;
cout <<"Enter Assignment Mark in Percentage: ";
cin >> AssMark;

        c.setAssNum(AssNum);
        c.setAssMark(AssMark);

        cout <<"The Mark for assignment "<< c.getAssNum() <<" is: " << c.getAssMark()<<"%";


    }
```

I don't expect anyone to rewrite the code, would just like some clarity, how to use arrays in this context.

Thank you

Comment: laughed at ass number

Comment: have a look at example and tutorial on std::vector

Comment: I have to say that your variable names are; how to put it; a little funny :)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Laughed at `AssMark`!

Comment: Haha Well Writing out Assignment is to much typing hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

First you create a class containing one assignment, that is a bit like you have it now in your assignments class, just call it `assignment` instead

Then create a container for the assignments, this contains a vector or array with your assignments. e.g.

```
class assignments
{
public:
  assignments() : m_assignments( new assignment[100] )
  {}
  ~assignments() { delete [] m_assignments; }
private:
  assignment* m_assignments;
};
```

better is to use `std::vector` see `#include <vector>`

you would then need to add public methods to access the array like

```
assignment getAssignment(int i);
void setAssignment(int i, const assignment& ass);
```

for instance